# Whats the difference between the outputs when directly using the variable and hostvars in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have ansible inventory with below entries in it.

```
[local]
localhost port=80

[apacheweb]
kputtegowda2c.mylabserver.com

[appserver]
kputtegowda3c.mylabserver.com
```

Now, if I want to access the host variable "port" of the local group. I have a simple playbook to display the variable value.

```
- hosts: local 
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - debug: var={{ port }}
```

the above sample produces the output.

```
TASK [debug] *************
ok: [localhost] => {
"80": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

instead of directly accessing the port variable if I use hostvars[inventory_hostname].port I get the output as below.

```
TASK [debug] ****************
ok: [localhost] => {
"hostvars[inventory_hostname].port": "80"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have used mustaches when you should not have; if you switch `var=` to `msg=` it will work as expected, but what you wrote is equivalent to:

```
  tasks:
  - debug: var=80
```

which is exactly what ansible runs, explaining the `"80": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED"` text